# A few questions regarding random points on a disk.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Today a few questions popped up in my head, and I'm curious to know the answers.

a). Let $C$ be a disk of radius $R$ centered at the origin. Given a point on the disk $P = (x,y)$, what is the expected distance between $P$ and $P'$, where $P'$ is a point chosen uniformly at random somewhere on the disk.

b). Let $C,R,P $ and $P'$ be as above. What is the probability that the distance between $P$ and $P'$ is $\geq r$, with $r\in [0,2R]$.

Help with either would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question says "disk", but the title says "circle". Do you mean circle or disk?

Comment: For b, the probability that the distance is $r$ is zero, because the distance is a continuous random variable.

Comment: You are right, I will edit the post to be more clear/capture what I mean. Thanks!

Comment: I believe the hardest part is how to write the area of the intersection of two circles using only lengths without any given angles. (My thought is to first determine the CDF.)

Comment: It's cool when the distance is small enough that all the possibilities fall inside the disc; but when the distance grows, part of the possibilities are outside, so the intersection area is the part that counts.

Comment: Maybe polar system works? 'cause it's a circle. (I haven't tried so I'm not sure.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$a$.) Let the initial point chosen be $p=(x_0, y_0)$. This gives us a distance from some other randomly chosen point on the disc of;

$$D(x,y)=\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2}$$

Integrating this over the entire disc and dividing by $A=\pi R^2$ gives us;

$$E(D)=\frac{1}{\pi R^2}\iint_{C}\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2}dxdy$$

Switching to polar coordinates yields;

$$E(D)=\frac{1}{\pi R^2}\iint_{C}\sqrt{(r\cos(\theta)-x_0)^2+(r\sin(\theta)-y_0)^2}rdrd\theta$$

Choosing $p=(0,0)$ makes this integral trivial but it is, in general, a big mess that you are free to crank through if you have the time.

$b$.) Now, we can consider the probability that the distance between $p$ and some other randomly chosen point $p'$ on the disc is $\geq r\in [0,2R]$ by considering the area of intersection between overlapping circles. That is, consider the disc of radius $R$ centered at the origin and a separate disc of radius $r$ centered at your chosen point $p$. Let $A_1$ be the overlap between these discs and let $A_2=\pi R^2-A_1$.
The probability that the distance from $p$ to $p'$ is $\geq r\in [0,2R]$ is then equal to the probability that $p'$ resides in the area $A_2$. That is;

$$P(|p-p'|\geq r)=\frac{A_2}{\pi R^2}=1-\frac{A_1}{\pi R^2}$$

Luckily for both of us, the formula for [Circle-Circle Intersection](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html) has already been worked out. This gives us;

$$P(|p-p'|\geq r)=1-\frac{A_1}{\pi R^2}$$

$$=1- \frac{1}{\pi R^2}\bigg[r^{2}\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{d^{2}+r^{2}-R^{2}}{2dr}\right)
+ R^{2}\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{d^{2}+R^{2}-r^{2}}{2dR}\right)
- \frac12 \sqrt{(-d+r+R)(d+r-R)(d-r+R)(d+r+R)}\bigg]$$

where $d=|p|=\sqrt{x_0^2+y_0^2}$.

Comment: Very clear, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that if $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ then, using the cosine rule, the density for the distance $d=PP'$ is proportional to

- $\dfrac{2d}{R^2}$ when $0 \le d\le R-z$
- $\dfrac{2d}{\pi R^2} \cos^{-1} \left(\dfrac{d^2+z^2-R^2}{2zd}\right)$ when $R-z < d < R+z$
- $0$ when $R+z \le d \le 2R$

I also suspect that it is possible but messy to do the integrations to find the expectation in closed form.

The following chart shows the densities for a unit disk $(R=1$ but more generally everything would scale by a factor of $R)$, with

- $z=0$ in red (expectation $\frac23$),
- $z=\frac R4$ in pink (expectation about $0.697794$),
- $z=\frac R2$ in black (expectation about $0.7896702$),
- $z=\frac{3R}{4}$ in cyan (expectation about $0.9374881$), and
- $z=R$ in blue (expectation about $1.131768$).

[image: densities with varying z]

and the expectations for varying $z$ look like:

[image: expectations]

If you also let $P$ vary uniformly over the disk, so $z$ has density $\frac{z}{2R^2}$ for $0<z<R$, then this would lead you to the expected distance between two points on the disk being the known $\frac{128}{45\pi}R$.